# Need help in understanding why overloaded equals method is not considered during the runtime

Tags: java

I cannot make sense of the following:
Let's say we have class **Point** with overloaded equals methods.

```
    public boolean equals(Object o){
      System.out.println("Called with argument of Object type");
      ...
    }

    public boolean equals(Point p){
      System.out.println("Called with argument of Point type");
      ...
    }
```

Then in the class **App** we do the following:

```
    Point p = new Point(3,4);
    Object op = new Point(3,4);
    op.equals(p);
```

This is what we get in the console:

*Called with argument of Object type*

Why is it the case? We are passing Point type as an argument and we should expect compiler to pick method with the closest type. Isn't it the case? 
My best guess is that at compile time the compiler grabs signature of a method from Object class and looks for EXACTLY same signature in the child class during the dynamic binding, so our overloaded class with argument of type Point is not seen.
Right? I am not sure if I am correct here but that is what I can think of...
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Overload* resolution and *override* resolution follows different rules. As a matter of fact, overload resolution is based *only* on the declared type of the expression on which you invoke the method, so all that matters is that you are calling a method on something that is declared to be an `Object`. Only when the method with the best signature match has been chosen (from among the declared type's methods) is the virtual call performed - at which point the actual type and its ancestors will be checked for overrides *of that particular method signature*.

(For the same reason, it would be impossible to call e.g. `distanceFromOrigo()` even if that were a method in `Point`, because the only available methods are the ones in `Object`.)

Answer (score 2):

When you call `equals` for a variable of type `Object`, it executes `Object`'s `equals`, which accepts an `Object` argument (or a method that overrides it - in your case - `public boolean equals(Object o)` of your `Point` class).

The compiler chooses `public boolean equals(Object o)` since the compile time type of `op` is `Object`. `Object` has no method with the signature - `public boolean equals(Point p)`, so the compiler can't choose this method.

Comment: I was briefly hoping for something much more complicated.